# change key-value in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Here is my code:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities"ng-model="selectedCity" class="form-control"></select>
```

And here is result :

```
<option label="NY" value="string:694">NY</option>
```

I want to show just *694* as value.
What I want :

```
<option label="NY" value="694">NY</option>
```

Any suggestion?

p.s. NY is value and 694 is key.

Comment: How does the structure of your cities object look exactly?

Comment: As you can see in [the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgRoeixAKRF4kakxTMyY?p=preview), although the value of the `option` element is indeed `string:694`, when you check what's inside `selectedCity` you get only 694.

Comment: This is also consistent with the Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) about the 'select' part of the ng-options expression: "select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent <select> element."

Answer (score 0):

If the object literals in the cities object looks like this:

```
$scope.cities = [{key: 694, val:"NY"}, {key: 695, val:"NJ"}];
```

You can modify your select control to this to get the expected output as you requested:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCity" class="form-control">
  <option value =""></option>
  <option ng-repeat="city in cities" label="{{city.val}}" value="{{city.key}}" >{{city.val}}</option>
</select>
```

Result:

```
<option label="NY" value="694">NY</option>
```